# Storing Default and Single Values in Objective-C using <CoreData/CoreData.h>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to store default values in a `Data Model` called `CoreData.xcdatamodeld`. The file includes a single entity called `Settings`. Within `Settings`, there are six `Boolean` values.

When the iOS application launches for the first time, I want the default values of `NO` to be set as default values for these six `Boolean` values. From there, changes can be made to the default value. I also only want a single value of `YES` or `NO` associated with each `Boolean` value in the `Settings` entity. After changes are made, and the application is cleared from memory, and restarted, the data model should include the latest values that have been defined by the user.

How would I go about doing this? I already have the structure in place to deal with those values and their ability to change, I was just wondering about this from a theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that using Core Data to store user preferences is a good idea.

Reduce and simplify your code by employing `NSUserDefaults`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:kStringMacro];
trueOrFalse = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kStringMacro];
```

Comment: I've looked into utilizing `NSUserDefaults` and it seems like a better, less complicated way of storing user data. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: How do you set the default value of a value in `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: You can check if a key exists at app start and set the default value there if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set a default value in the core data model.

[image]