# Saving nullable values in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nullable, magicalrecord

if my json response is an empty object, i want to handle this case by not creating an OPLocationModel
my json response is the following "location":{} -> an empty object,

example:
location - has an id

```
NSDictionary *locationData = data[@"location"];
if(locationData){
  OPLocationModel *locationModel = [OPLocationModel modelWithJSONData:locationData withContext:context];
  model.location = locationModel;
}
else{
 model.location = nil;
}
```

is this the best approach to do this or is there better suggestion?

---

solved

```
NSDictionary *locationData = data[@"location"];
if([locationData objectForKey:@"id"] != nil){

    OPLocationModel *locationModel = [OPLocationModel modelWithJSONData:locationData withContext:context];
    model.location = locationModel;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24581687/1801544 ?

Comment: Try [NSNull null]. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to set `NSString` for this property, as its type is `OPLocationModel`, isn't it?

Comment: @MichałCiuba what do you suggest?  setting the OPLocationModel to nil?

Comment: @Hala I'm just suggesting that a string might be an invalid value for this property.  Why did you need to set it to an empty string? What problem were you trying to solve this way?

Comment: Yes you're right @MichałCiuba. I've edited the question and I found the solution and I'll edit to  add it.